# .remove() is not working on my specific reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database:

[image]

And I want to delete the "small_green" value, so I'm trying with this:

```
const refToDelete = firebase.database().ref().child('products').orderByChild('fruits').equalTo('small_green');
refToDelete.remove();
```

But it throws this error:

[image]

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs) tutorial and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?) documentation.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only call `remove()` on a `DatabaseReference`, which is a reference to an exact location in the database.

Your `firebase.database().ref().child('products').orderByChild('fruits').equalTo('small_green')` is a query, which is not a exact location. That means you can't call `remove()` on it. You will first have to execute the query to get the matching locations, and then call `remove()` on each of those.

Typically this will be something along the lines of:

```
const query = firebase.database().ref().child('products').orderByChild('fruits').equalTo('small_green');
query.once('value', functions(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    childSnapshot.ref.remove();
  });
})
```

Aside from that you're ordering on the wrong child node (as you said in the comments). So you'll want:

```
const query = firebase.database().ref().child('products/fruits').orderByChild('attrs').equalTo('small_green');
```

Comment: works with const query = firebase.database().ref().child('fruits').orderByChild('attrs').equalTo('small_green'); we where wrong putting 'products' on the .child(, because products is the database name. It throws this warning: "FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. your data wil..." but it works. Ty

Comment: I've accepted your answer but please change that .child('products').orderByChild('fruits')... to .child('fruits').orderByChild('attrs')...